# Testing a simple component is rendered when wrapped by withFormik() using JEST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, formik

I have a simple component with some input and dropdown elements, I am trying to test that the elements are rendered. By finding the element 'input' in my expect statement.

Here is what I tried in my test file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import AddUser from '../Components/AddUser'

describe('AddUser', () => {
  let wrapper
  let mockFetchDetailsActions
  let mockHandleCancel
  const match = {
    params: { id: '1212212' }
  }
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockFetchDetailsActions = jest.fn()
    mockHandleCancel = jest.fn()
    wrapper = shallow(
      <AddUser
        match={match}
        actions={{
          fetchDetailsActions: mockFetchDetailsActions,
          handleCancel: mockHandleCancel
        }}
      />
    )
  })

  describe('Component rendered', () => {
    it('Elements rendered correctly', () => {
      expect(wrapper.find('input').length).toBe(6)
    })
  })
})
```

Here is my component:

```
/* eslint-disable no-invalid-this */
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import GridContainer from './Grid/GridContainer'
import GridItem from './Grid/GridItem'
import { TextField } from 'formik-material-ui'
import { Field, Form } from 'formik'
import dashboardStyle from '../styles/dashboardStyle'
import Card from './Card/Card'
import CardBody from './Card/CardBody'
import * as Constants from '../actions/actionTypes'
import SaveAndCancelButtons from './Common/saveAndCancelButtons'

class AddUser extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    if (this.props.match.params.id) {
      this.props.actions.fetchDetailsActions(Constants.FETCH_DETAILS_API_CALL_REQUEST, this.props.match.params.id)
    } else {
      this.props.actions.handleCancel()
    }
  }

  handleChange = name => event => {
    this.props.actions.handleInputChangeAction(name, event.target.value)
  }

  onSave = () => {
    const userDetails = {
      user: this.props.values.user
    }
    if (userDetails && userDetails.user.id) {
      this.props.actions.updateDetailsActions(Constants.UPDATE_USER_API_CALL_REQUEST, userDetails.user.id, userDetails)
    } else {
      this.props.actions.addNewUserAction(Constants.ADD_USER_API_CALL_REQUEST, userDetails)
    }
  }

  handleCancel = () => {
    this.props.history.push('/admin_console')
    this.props.actions.handleCancel()
  }
  render () {
    const { classes, isFetching } = this.props
    return (
      <Form>
        <Field
          name="user"
          render={feildProps => (
            <Fragment>
              <GridContainer>
                <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
                  <Card>
                    <h2 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Add User</h2>
                    <CardBody isFetching={isFetching}>
                      <GridContainer>
                        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
                          <Field
                            label="First Name"
                            name={`user.first_name`}
                            className={this.props.classes.textField}
                            margin="normal"
                            variant="outlined"
                            component={TextField}
                          />
                          <Field
                            label="Secondary Email"
                            name={`user.email_secondary`}
                            className={this.props.classes.textField}
                            margin="normal"
                            variant="outlined"
                            component={TextField}
                          />
                        </GridItem>
                        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
                          <Field
                            label="Last Name"
                            name={`user.last_name`}
                            className={this.props.classes.textField}
                            margin="normal"
                            variant="outlined"
                            component={TextField}
                          />
                          <Field
                            label="Mobile Phone"
                            name={`user.mobile_phone`}
                            className={this.props.classes.textField}
                            margin="normal"
                            variant="outlined"
                            component={TextField}
                          />
                        </GridItem>
                        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
                          <Field
                            label="Email"
                            name={`user.email`}
                            className={this.props.classes.textField}
                            margin="normal"
                            variant="outlined"
                            component={TextField}
                          />
                          <Field
                            label="Work Phone"
                            name={`user.work_phone`}
                            className={this.props.classes.textField}
                            margin="normal"
                            variant="outlined"
                            component={TextField}
                          />
                        </GridItem>
                      </GridContainer>
                    </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                  <SaveAndCancelButtons
                    handleSave={() => {
                      this.onSave()
                    }}
                    routingLink="/people"
                    label="Save"
                  />
                </GridItem>
              </GridContainer>
            </Fragment>
          )}
        />
      </Form>
    )
  }
}

AddUser.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default withStyles(dashboardStyle)(AddUser)
```

Here is my withFormik() wrapper:

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { withFormik } from 'formik'
import * as Yup from 'yup'
import AddUser from './AddUser'

const styles = theme => ({
  textField: {
    width: '100%'
  }
})

const validations = Yup.object().shape({
  user: Yup.object().shape({
    first_name: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    last_name: Yup.string().required('Required')
  })
})

const withFormikWrapper = withFormik({
  validationSchema: validations,
  enableReinitialize: true
})(AddUser)

export default withStyles(styles)(withFormikWrapper)
```

Expected result:

Found 6 elements.

Actual Results:

```
 AddUser › Component rendered › Elements rendered correctly

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 6
    Received: 0

      26 |   describe('Component rendered', () => {
      27 |     it('Elements rendered correctly', () => {
    > 28 |       expect(wrapper.find('input').length).toBe(6)
         |                                            ^
      29 |     })
      30 |   })
      31 | })
```

Comment: Have you tried using `render` instead of `shallow` in your test?

Comment: I think, mount and render acts similarly, I want to unit test only this component, so used shallow as always I use for regular components(without formik), and which works.

Comment: @mattThomas what I actually mean is when I try shallow for regular components (without formik) it works.
Thanks For the reply.

Comment: Ok try using https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/debug.html to see what is rendered. I don’t think shallow will render the nested children.

Comment: Nope, It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with `mount` instead of `shallow`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by using **mount** and also imported the component from **withFormikWrapper()** instead of importing from its own.

**In test file:**

before:

import AddUser from '../Components/AddUser'

Now:

import AddUser from '../Components/AddUserWithFormik'